# Fish seems to remember things through reinstallation

Tags: fish

I'm trying to troubleshoot something with fish shell, so I uninstalled it from my Mac, including deleting everything from `~/.config/fish` and reinstalled it. I found that it seems to remember some things, such as its autocomplete history. Is there some file I've missed in the uninstall process? Or is fish sharing autocomplete/history data with zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/history.html) says:

> By default interactive commands are logged to $XDG_DATA_HOME/fish/fish_history (typically ~/.local/share/fish/fish_history)

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Sure enough, that's got entries back to May of this year. I wonder why the uninstallation instructions don't include clearing that file out.